# PHP How to check if array has not key and value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using one custom CMS developed by someone and getting issue to check the array result.

The function returns an array of username by passing userids array.

## Example Code

```
$all_users = "1,5,9,10,25,40"; // getting from database

$user_ids = explode(',', $all_users);
$usernames  = get_userids_to_usernames($user_ids); //this returns usernames array by passing uesrids array
```

If the database has not users in the column than the function is returning weird empty / null array as below.

### var_dump($usernames);

```
array(1) { [""]=> NULL }
```

### print_r($usernames);

```
(
    [] => 
)
```

Now issue is, I want to check if array is empty or has value in return but I have tried everything `is_null`, `empty`, `count($usernames) > 0` but none of these working.

**Can anyone please help me to check conditionally if array has value or empty like above empty result.**

Comment: That's not empty though. Can you just test if there is a single item, with key "" and a value of null? 3-4 conditions (is_array, count, isset, ==(=)), one if.

Comment: use `is_null()` to check if value is null

Comment: @splash58 yes I have tested all these and I am getting same `false` result. Any idea how to check it so can use conditional statement for such result?

Comment: @niklaz `is_null` not working as well.

Comment: `"1,5,9,10,25,40"; // getting from database` why would a database return CSV ID's?

Comment: `if(is_array($usernames) && count($usernames) === 1 && isset($usernames['']) && $usernames[''] === null)`?

Comment: @Scuzzy this is not my app so no idea but it is returning in this way.

Comment: I would check at the query level. If you get results you have a match. Also delimited columns are a bad design.

Comment: @CodeLover `if(empty($array) or empty(current($array))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array` to check if the array has an empty value and `array_key_exists` to check the key.

```
in_array("", $array)
array_key_exists("", $array)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: This seems working but would test with other answers too. Just to find best solution.

Comment: @CodeLover and how does it work if in_array search value but `''` is key ?

Comment: Check does the array have element which value is an empty string by making php cast types? It's the best way to end with a pile of bugs

Comment: @splash58 the biggest issue here is by checking `empty` or `count` doesn't works here as it is returning `false` So I believe @Dialex solutions works (I have tested) and @line88 solution works too. Now need to see which is better.

Comment: @splash58 @Code Lover You can use ```array_key_exists``` to check for empty keys as well. I just forgot that you were looking for that. You can maybe use them combined in a if like that: ```if(in_array("", $array) || array_key_exists("", $array))```

Comment: I updated my answer so it matches better with the question

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround

```
if (array_key_exists('', $a) && $a[''] === null) {
    unset($a['']);
}
```

then check on emptiness

Comment: This looks like the safest of the suggested solutions. With a custom made CMS you can't expect that it will always behave the same, and this answer takes that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through array, and check if keys or values are empty or null

```
$newarray = [];
foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
    if(is_null($value) || trim($value) == '' || is_null($value) || trim($key) == ''){
    continue; //skip the item
  }
        $newarray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use empty with it, try array filter

```
if (empty(array_filter($arr))) {
    //Do something
}
```

Array filter will automatically remove falsey values for you, and you can include a callback should you need more flexability.